# Installling a complated laravel 5 project on vps with ssh and git

Tags: git, laravel, ssh, vps

I made one laravel 5 project in my localhost.
I bought a vps. I want to install my laravel 5 project to vps but I don't want use ftp.

Because, I will oft-times upgrade my project with my bit-bucket account. Otherwise, I using my vps for a few websites. Because of this I don't want use public_html folder.

I installed all requirements.

Can someone help me?

Comment: first install git and composer in your vps,then you can clone,update your project using git in any folder and then create a config file for run this project using domain name

Comment: how i create a config file for this? Can you show a example me?

Comment: for create nginx configuration file follow this http://www.kingpabel.com/nginx-virtual-host/

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/). It's a ruby library that's meant for deploying code to servers, and is nicely configurable. It's written in Ruby, but can deploy code written in any language. You can extend it in a number of ways if necessary. By default it deploys via git (actually generates a release .tar.gz and unzips it in the endpoint). It connects over SSH. It handles releases and rollbacks as well. Pretty nice IMHO.

There's a plugin for Laravel projects also: https://github.com/capistrano/laravel/